# Do I need to wait for a callback on a call to WATCH in Redis (in node.js)?

Tags: node.js, redis, watch

I'm using `node-redis`. In code like this:

```
var store = require('redis').createClient();
store.watch('some:key');
store.get('some:key', function (err, results) {
   var multi = store.multi();
   // COMPUTE SOMETHING WITH results
   multi.set('something:or:other', 25);
   multi.exec(checkAllIsWell);
});
```

Should lines 1-2 read

```
store.watch('some:key', function (err, alwaysok) {
  store.get('some:key', function (err, result) {
```

or will `watch` always have immediate effect?

EDIT: To reframe the question a little, is sequence guaranteed on seqential calls on the same Redis client? Or could the WATCH happen after the GET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having reframed my question, I realize that it must surely be sequence-preserving, and I'm actually duplicating this question: [Are Redis updates synchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271779/are-redis-updates-synchronous)

So the answer is surely that I don't need to wait for WATCH to call back and my original code is OK.

Sorry to noise up the web, folks!

Answer (score 1):

Watch always returns OK. http://redis.io/commands/watch

It is useful only if later you use MULTI/EXEC, to check the EXEC return value.

For more information about Redis transactions, visit http://redis.io/topics/transactions

Comment: Well, in `node-redis`, WATCH always _calls back_ with an OK (but _returns_ true). The question though is whether it always takes effect and calls back with OK immediately.

Comment: The ordering of the commands should be the same whether or not you wait for the callback or not, and that's all that matters.

Comment: Thanks, @Theo, for helping clarify.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I misunderstood the question. @Grumdrig if you don't wait for the callback, it probably works as [pipelining](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining).